# How to detect 404 routes (NoMatch) when doing SSR with "react-router-dom" without using <Redirect>?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, http-status-code-404, react-router-dom, server-side-rendering

I'm using `react-router-dom` and I'm implementing **SSR** (Server Side Rendering) to my web app.

I'm having trouble on how to handle `404` routes.

**My goal:**

- Whenever someone visits a `/non-existent-route` on my web app. ***I DON'T want to redirect them.*** They should stay on that very same route, and they should get `HTTP status 404` along with the `404 Page`.

**This should be the sequence:**

- `REQ GET /non-existent-route`
- `RES 404 /non-existent-route` along with the HTML for the `404 Page`

**Example:**

A user tries to access a path that **does not match any route**.

It should be *"captured"* by my last `<Switch>` `<Route>` and the `Page404` gets rendered. Just like this [example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/no-match) from the official docs.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path={"/route1"} component={Component1}/>
  <Route exact path={"/route2"} component={Component2}/>
  <Route path={"*"} component={Page404}/>
</Siwtch>
```

When I'm rendering it using `renderToString` from `react-dom/server`, this is what I do:

From: [react-router docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/server-rendering)

[image]

If I was redirecting it to a 404, I could use the `context.url` to detect that a redirect has happened (like the example from the doc below). But I don't want to redirect. I want to return the `404` status on that very same route. Therefore I cannot use `context.url` to detect the 404 route.

[image]

---

**QUESTION**

How to detect that no specific route was matched and the `Page404` was rendered when I'm not redirecting from the render?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out how to do it.

From the [official docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/server-rendering/adding-app-specific-context-information) we get that:

You can add information to the `staticContext`. And that information will be added to the `context` object even if you don't `<Redirect/>` from the render.

[image]

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-sound-dqoog) with this example:

**App.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path={"*"}
        render={({ staticContext }) => {
          if (staticContext) {
            staticContext.statusCode = 404;
          }
          return <div>WHATEVER</div>;
          // return <Redirect to="/404" />;
        }}
      />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

**index.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import App from "./App";

// ON THE SERVER
const context = {};

const html = renderToString(
  <StaticRouter location={"/"} context={context}>
    <App />
  </StaticRouter>
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(context));
```

This is the result (logged from `index.tsx`). As expected:

[image]